# How to call Spring Controller's method with @RequestBody from JUNIT test case

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I have one controller method .

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody 
    public String uploadFiles(@RequestBody MyModel myModel) {...}
```

And I have to call this from JUNIT test cases.

So far I tried different ways, some of them is below and its giving me

`java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<415>`

```
MvcResult result;   
            result = getMockMvc().perform(post("/fileUpload"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
```

and

```
result = getMockMvc().perform(post("/fileUpload").accept(APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                        .andReturn();
```

I can't pass my param in RequestHeader, RequestParam or PathVariable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP status 415 means unsupported media type, which means the controller isnt receiving the request media type that it was expecting.

If you're setting `accept(APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8)` in your JUnit test case, then your controller should also have `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` as part of its `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Edit: And if you're only asking specifically how to append a request body to your junit test, you can add:

`result = getMockMvc().perform(post("/fileUpload"))
                    .content("payload string")
                    .contentType("application/json; charset=utf-8")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();`

Comment: Yes, Its working now. Was not setting content(...). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(jsonContent)).andReturn();
```

Where url = "/fileUpload" and jsonContent is your request json content in String type.

Comment: Thanks @Minh. Your approach is also right. But we could add `.andExpect(status().isOk())` as well.